# server-side SQL library

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, performance

Does a library exist in .net that can perform queries server-side?

The reason I ask is even though I've used many tricks to maximize database performance such as `SELECT`ing and `JOIN`ing on the `PRIMARY`, using `INT`s as the `PRIMARY`, fixed `LENGTH`s, `UPDATE`ing instead of `DELETE`ing, no `NULL`s for columns to be `UPDATE`d, and `UPDATE`ing tables by using an `INT` "state" column (such as "active", "inactive", etc), but latency times go from <10ms to >100ms just by using a few `SELECT`s with 1 `JOIN` each using the techniques above.

I'm going to start using the server to `JOIN` instead because I've had lots of success with driving lag back down <10ms doing so, but I'm wondering if there's already a library or built-in feature that can do this.

An example would be breaking a single `JOIN` query into multiple queries:

1. `SELECT` a specific row from a `table1` based upon the `PRIMARY` key
2. `SELECT` a specif row from `table2` based upon the `PRIMARY` located in `table1`

And the complexity only increases from there.  Does such a library/feature exist for .net?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: All the database related queries are performed on the server side, I am not really sure what are you looking for, are you looking for [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Comment: Are there indexes on the columns you're querying?

Comment: @Habib thanks for looking!  no, i want to break apart more complex queries to drive lag back down.  from the example of a basic `JOIN`, i want just two basic `SELECT`s.  i've done this manually, and the results are great, but instead of developing my own huge `class`, i was hoping this was already done

Comment: @syrion thanks for looking!  absolutely.  it's not the end of the world when I do a single `JOIN` off the `PRIMARY`, but it does go up a few 10s of ms.  Considering ping lag is 50ms, it starts to add up.  When I can't `JOIN` off the `PRIMARY`, it gets really bad.

Comment: @Habib excuse my poor vocab.  when i say "server-side", i mean vb.net, c#, php, RoR, c++ etc.  i want to depend less on the database for "thinking" since it's slower than even PHP (i've sped up my personal site by leaning more upon PHP than MySQL)

Comment: Interesting.  Does doing multiple selects *total* less time than the joins?  That would be unusual in my experience.  Are you doing these with a single database connection?

Comment: @syrion it's crazy!  i didn't believe it myself until i tried it.  of course, it depends upon how many queries are being done.  single connection (but want to risk persistent now that we're 100% AJAX.  shaved off 10ms on my personal site that way.  no `TRANSACTION`s server-side).  for 2+ `JOIN`s, it's hands down faster even when `JOIN`ing off the `PRIMARY`.  sorting is very much better server-side, especially when complex.  I'm thinking that when I need to `SELECT` tons of rows this way (150k+), i need to see if I can maximize the SQL statement length with as many `IN`s as possible lol

Comment: Can we chat about this a bit? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23674/weird-query-chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). Using LINQ, you can query data in code in such a way that the query expressions are converted to SQL and optimized (as best as possible) to get the data you're querying.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion!  does it avoid `JOIN`s and sorting on the database?  does it do all of the "thinking" server-side?