# server-side SQL include

Tags: php, mysql, performance, include

This is the php version of this question [server-side SQL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618438/server-side-sql-library)

Is there a library that can break apart sql into fully server-side logic?

As an example consider this basic query `SELECT table1column1, table2column1 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = 1 AND table2.table1id = table1.id;` which is ~5x slower than breaking up the `SELECT` into 2 `SELECT`s `SELECT`ing off the `PRIMARY` for both, assuming that `table2.table1id` is not the `PRIMARY`.

I would want a library, that in this case, does just that, breaks up the single query into two.  It doesn't have to parse sql to understand what one wants rather it would probably be best in something like this format `basicJoin($table1columnsList, $table2columnsList, $table1name, $table2name, $table1id, $table2table1idColumnName)`.

This function would

1. `SELECT` the `table1` columns specified into an array based upon `$table1id` (the `PRIMARY`)
2. `SELECT` all `table2` ids (`table2`'s `PRIMARY`) and `table1id`s into an array and find the proper `table2` id
3. use the `table2` id above to `SELECT` the `table2` columns specified into an array (or in the `table1` array)

Handling my logic in php only has vastly decreased processing lag and processing lag spikes, but it's tedious writing out all of this logic.

Does it already exist?  If so, where?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If a simple join is 5x slower than quering each table seperately you have some serious index issues or something else. There is _no way_ that join is slower.

Comment: @hank negative, putting an index on `table2.table1id` makes the example query take 30ms vs 6ms for 2 `SELECT`s off the primaries.  php sorting negligible

Comment: Is that just the database time, or are you including the round trip time for performing multiple queries?

Comment: @Barmar no cloud.  same machine.  yes, i don't recommend this for systems on the cloud considering cost, etc.  so, the php sorting adds a ms or 2 at worst.  all-in processing for php sorting method is 7 to 8 ms.  i can only imagine how much faster things can be with hiphop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're into OOP there's Propel - http://propelorm.org/ It handles all the logic and gives you methods like `joinWith()` and `getThis()`, `setThat()`, `save()`.

It appears Propel does break queries apart, so that it can deliver several objects that can be saved individually.

Comment: very nice!  does it `SELECT` off the `PRIMARY` tho?  that's the source of the speed

Comment: you mean like: `findPks()` - http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#retrieving_rows

Comment: it makes me want to cry!  ty!  the deeper i get in, the better php is by far than .net.  you can only pay me to make me use it.  lol  the sadness is building  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825354/session-write-close-session-open-for-aspx-asmx

Comment: eh. it gets irritating with complicated queries. You're in for a ride on the documentation roller coaster. enjoy.